# Alternative to SET ANSI_NULLS OFF in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SP that has a very complex SQL statement(s) where I need to be able to compare some column to NULL e.g.

```
...
FROM Categories
WHERE PID = @parentID
```

`@parentID` is a SP parameter which **can** be valid NULL.
`PID` (parent ID) is `uniqueidentifier` which can also be valid NULL (top level category).
I could use `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ANSI_NULLS_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) says:

> In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and
>   any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate
>   an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan
>   to modify applications that currently use this feature.

What can be an elegant way instead of repeating the same query(s) with `IS NULL` in case `@parentID=NULL` (and also not using dynamic SQL):

```
IF @parentID IS NULL 
  SELECT...WHERE PID IS NULL
ELSE
  SELECT...WHERE PID = @parentID
```

**EDIT:** I want to avoid an `IF` because I hate repeating (huge) code.

Comment: What's wrong with your `IF...ELSE`? It's clear, simple and efficient

Comment: The `if` method is probably the best method, particularly with `recompile` to ensure that both versions will use an index when the stored procedure is compiled.

Comment: You could always vote for SQL Server to add support for the ANSI [`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate), but it's been open for ten years and I've not heard even a whisper of it being implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
select ..
FROM Categories
WHERE PID = @parentID or (PID is null and @parentID is null)
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this ignore the index on PID?

Comment: @zig Well, it will not "ignore" index at all (if you have corresponding one). But in SQL Server `or` operator is not a sargable one - so instead of "index seek" you will find "index scan" in execution plan, and this is less efficient than index seek in most cases. If it is performance-critical in your case - you have to use approach suggested by Gordon Linoff or your initial approach using `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the info. it's really not performance-critical in this specific case. this is why I choose your solution, it's clear and short and it works fine for me. I will investigate further on the index.

Comment: BTW, wouldn't it it better to use: `WHERE (PID = @parentID and @parentID is not null) or (PID is null and @parentID is null)`? I assume SQL will shortcut the `PID = @parentID` when `@parentID is null`...

Comment: `PID = @parentID and @parentID is not null` is redundant condition, because when `@parentID` is null first part of condition will never be satisfied and when it is not null - second part is redundant ;)

Comment: So SQL handles `PID = @parentID` as FALSE immediately when `@parendID` is NULL? there is no scan/seek?

Comment: yes, you can try and see it on some example like `select * from some_table where somecolumn = null` - just run it and look into execution plan. SQL Server query optimizer is smart enough, so if condition will never be satisfied - it will not perform index/table scan or seek.

Answer (score 4):

I think the `if` version is the clearest.  A big issue with multiple queries, though, is that the stored procedure compiles the code when it is first run -- and it might make the wrong decision about the execution plan.

One option is to include `recompile`.

Another is to combine the queries, but in a way where each part should use indexes effectively:

```
select c.* from categories c where pid is null and @parentid is null
union all
select c.* from categories c where pid = @parentId;
```

This is a tiny bit less efficient than the `if` version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant and concise way to code this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories
WHERE COALESCE(PID, 'NULL-MATCH') = COALESCE(@parentID, 'NULL-MATCH')
```

Comment: You are loosing the index here